# How to allow 80 port of the GCP VM instance?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have setup my react project on GCP VM instance and try to access it on port 80

Here is my Nginx setting

```
server {
    server_name 12.13.14.15;
    location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    ...
    }
}
```

But if I go to http://12.13.14.15 on the browser, it is off
So I checked the 80 port with a port checker and it is closed even though it is on the traffic rule of the GCP instance.

[image]

How to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: It's a bad practice. Put a HTTP load balancer in front of your VM.

Comment: Is that a solution for this?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you have enabled the VPC Firewall rule for Compute Engine instances with the tag `http-server`. Is your VM tagged? Do you have an OS level firewall such as `ufw`? Is `nginx` listening on port 80? Add the output from the command `netstat -tuln`. Your post lacks the configuration and debugging steps you used to solve this problem. You are overlooking something very basic.

Comment: ufw is not there. And nginx is not listening on port 80.

Comment: tcp 0.0.0.0:22 , 127.0.0.1:38575, 0.0.0.0:9000, 127.0.0.1:8998,  :::22, :::922, :::970, :::981, :::980  This is the result of that command

Comment: Put details in your post, and not via comments. If you don't have a service listening on port 80, why do you expect that you can connect? Edit your post with details on your configuration and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In GCP VM instance enable the HTTP traffic and HTTPS traffic in the firewall settings section [image: you can find in the below image for your reference]

Comment: Thanks. I did it but not works

Comment: I think you have used an internal IP as a server_name in the nginx config. Try to use a Public IP or domain

Comment: I used external IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Container-Optimized OS then the  default firewall configuration might be different.

> By default, the Container-Optimized OS host firewall allows only
> outgoing connections, and accepts incoming connections only through
> the SSH service. To accept incoming connections on a
> Container-Optimized OS instance, you must open the ports your services
> are listening on.

Configure the firewall rules by following this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/firewall) for Container-Optimized OS  and also verify [VPC Firewalls rules](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/firewalls). If you are still facing issues then perform these [troubleshooting steps](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests) for the connectivity test.

---

**Edit :** As per the [nginx listen module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) you need to mention the port which needs to listen. Can you try by adding the below configuration to your nginx setting.

```
server {
listen 80;
    server_name 12.13.14.15;
    location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Adrian Botteon : I have edited my answer, kindly try by using the above configuration and let me know the response.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work

Comment: @AdrianBotteon : Are you getting any syntax error and Post adding above configuration you need to restart the nginx to reflect the changes. Check whether port 80 is available or not.

Comment: No error. Also I found something weird. If I lost the connection of the console of the instance, nginx is not found so I have to reinstall it. Also pm2 is the same. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @AdrianBotteon : maybe 80 port is used in any other service in the same project. Kindly cross check the same and also post the configuration you are using . so that it will be easy for us to replicate the issue. Also pm2 is the same what is pm2 here ?